# How to write a String to fixed-size text files in Java?

Tags: java, string, file, io

I have a very long string and I want to write it to several text files of fixed size. For example, I want to set the size to be 1MB per file, and label each file as "text01.txt", "text02.txt"...

How can I achieve this in the simplest way?

Comment: How do you think you might do this? What have you tried so far?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows a lack of minimal understanding about the problem being solved.

Comment: I believe I have stated the problem clearly. Simply being unfamiliar with Java IO methods, couple of lines of Java would do. If you say it's not a suitable question for this site, fine. People don't have to be condescending about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep track of the number of bytes you're writing, and when it reaches a specified point, close the existing file and continue in a new one. There's no need to analyze the size of the file, since you know exactly what's going into it.

Something like this:

```
long fileSizeByteLimit = 5000000;
long bytesOutput = 0;

while(THEREAREMORELINESTOOUTPUT)  {

   //Open a new file
   while(bytesOutput <= fileSizeByteLimit)  {
      writer.append(lineOfOutput);
      bytesOutput += lineOfOutput.length();
   }
   //Close file

}
```

Comment: Care to elaborate a bit in a short code example? What file writing method to use so I can keep track of the number of bytes when writing texts?